# jQuery XPath plugin setting attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xpath

This question is about Sergey Ilinsky's jQuery XPath plugin. I have an xml file which I navigate it through this plugin. The file itself is not important to see. The question is more related to functionality of the plugin.

```
        var elemList = $(xmlDoc).xpath("call-script/option" + xpathExtension);
        for (var i = 0; i < elemList.length; i++) {
            if (elemList[i].getAttribute('text') != null) {
                alert(elemList[i].getAttribute('text'));
                //elemList[i].getAttribute('text') = 'example';
            }
        }
```

I would like to set the **text** attribute of the selected node as shown in commented out line. `getAttribute` works like a charm when I use it only for reading purposes. I would like to assign it with some kind of a `setAttribute` function which is not available. Any help from you would be much appreciated.

Plugin's link: http://plugins.jquery.com/xpath/

Plugin's version: 0.2.4

**Edit:** I think I should share part of my xml to give a better understanding.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<call-script say="Good morning">
    <option text="caller asks for blah">
    ...
       ...
    ...
    </option>
    <option text="caller requests blah">
    ...
       ...
    ...
    <option text="caller would like to blah">
    ...
       ...
    ...
    </option>
</call-script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is a `setAttribute` function as well.

```
 elemList[i].setAttribute('text','example');
```

This has fixed my problem. Sorry for hassling you.

Tutorial link: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/met_element_setattribute.asp

Answer (score 0):

You've already got jQuery, so you can be a little more efficient if you use jQuery's `.attr()` function, which does double-duty as both a getter and setter depending on the arguments. The `$.each()` function can be used here as well.

Rewriting your sample:

```
$.each(elemList, function(key, element) {   // iterate over each thing in elemList
    if (element.attr('text') !== null) {   // without 2nd argument, just returns the value
        alert(element.attr('text'));   // same
        element.attr('text', 'example');   // with 2nd argument, sets the value
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: I like the approach. However it gives 'element.attr is not a function' error. The xml that I parse is not html.